# How to lsof but ignore TID or PID

Tags: awk

The reason is that I want to catch the lsof size by lsof|awk '{print $7}'. However, some processes have the TID which would cause I get the wrong column awk '{print $8}' instead of awk '{print $7}'.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmMM2.png)

Comment: Please, never use images to show text. They are not searchable and cannot be copy-pasted (not mentioning the waste of storage). Just copy-paste your text and [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to parse the default output from `lsof`, you should use the format specifier, `-F`.

Check `man lsof` and search for `OUTPUT FOR OTHER PROGRAMS` and check out the available format specifiers with `lsof -F\?`.

In your case, you may be interested in something like:

```
lsof -Fs
```